# Why can't I reach Glassfish admin gui?

Tags: google-chrome, user-interface, glassfish

Either I start Glassfish domain from NetBeans or from the `asadmin` console, I can't reach the admin panel.

When I navigate to `http://localhost:4848`, first there's a page saying *"The Admin Console is starting. Please wait."*, then it tries to redirect to a page having title *"Login"*, but it loads, loads, loads forever. My CPU usage reaches 100% and nothing happens until I stop the server.

I tried Glassfish v3.1, v3.1.2 and also the freshest v4.0, without any modification.

About a year ago, v3.1 worked for me; I have no idea what could happen.

The server log says Glassfish can't find image files.

I uploaded the server log here: http://notepad.cc/share/LvaZvH23sF

I read somewhere that renaming the `console-updatecenter-plugin.jar`, and the `NO_NETWORK=true` option can solve similar problems, but these couldn't help for me.

I use JDK 7, and I'm on Windows 7 if it matters.

---

**(edit) Summarizing what happened, from my past comments:**

- The admin panel was unreachable in Google Chrome and [Internet Exlorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18041609/why-cant-i-reach-glassfish-admin-gui#comment26396296_18042801).
- I managed to reach the admin panel in [Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18041609/why-cant-i-reach-glassfish-admin-gui#comment26396296_18042801), and even in Chrome's [incognito mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18041609/why-cant-i-reach-glassfish-admin-gui#comment26400071_18042801), but the cause [was not AdBlock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18041609/why-cant-i-reach-glassfish-admin-gui#comment26397884_18042801).
- Chrome dev console complained about a [404 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18041609/why-cant-i-reach-glassfish-admin-gui#comment26396296_18042801).
- **After a while**, I was able to reach the admin panel in Chrome, in [normal mode too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18041609/why-cant-i-reach-glassfish-admin-gui#comment26421865_18041755), so from that point **I couldn't reproduce the problem**.

Comment: OMG, I was using chrome and had same trouble reaching Payara 5.181 server admin page, firefox did just good.

Comment: Had this problem, but resolved after clearing FF browser cache.

Answer (score 12):

Try accessing the console using this url: `http://localhost:4848/login.jsf`
`http://localhost:4848` doesnot redirect to `http://localhost:4848/common/index.jsf` as the url doesnot exists.

Answer (score 4):

I noticed this in your log:

> [2013-08-04T10:52:12.761+0200] [glassfish 4.0] [WARNING] [] [javax.enterprise.system.container.web.com.sun.web.security] [tid: _ThreadID=34 _ThreadName=admin-listener(2)] [timeMillis: 1375606332761] [levelValue: 900] [[
>     Context path from ServletContext:  differs from path from bundle: /]]

Following that warning, there are a lot of info messages that the server can't find resources that it expects:

> [2013-08-04T10:52:16.495+0200] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO] [] [com.sun.jsftemplating] [tid: _ThreadID=133 _ThreadName=admin-listener(6)] [timeMillis: 1375606336495] [levelValue: 800] [[
>     JSFT0004: The requested resource (/images/button/primary-mini-roll.gif) is not available.]]

...etc.

I'm curious as to how you installed the Glassfish servers. Did you use the windows installer? If you simply used the installer to update an existing Glassfish installation, an incorrect configuration could have been carried over.

The easiest solution to your problem is to download the ZIP distribution. Extract that to a new directory, start the asadmin tool via the command line and run the command:

```
asadmin> start-domain domain1
```

That should give you a completely fresh installation and should work without any problems. [There's a good blog post here on getting started with Glassfish 4](http://blog.c2b2.co.uk/2013/06/getting-started-with-glassfish-4.html), it would be worth skimming through to make sure there's nothing you've missed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I followed exactly what you said: I extracted the ZIP distribution and typed that command in asadmin. The problem is the same.

Comment: In that case, I think we can rule out the problem being with Glassfish. Here's a few things that I would want to investigate first:
1) Is there another Glassfish running on port 4848? Use `netstat` in the command line to find out.
2) Does the same error occur if you use the IP address of your machine?
3) Is it the same in other browsers?

Chrome has some good browser tools to help you see what's going on. Press F12 and look at the "console" tab.

Comment: 1) there is no another Glassfish running, but netstat lists 7 lines with port 4848, even after I stopped the Glassfish domain.2) When I type in my IP:4848, the browser says it can't connect. 3) The problem described above occured with Chrome. But Firefox CAN load the admin page! Internet Explorer cannot connect. When I hit F12 in Chrome, the Console tab says the following: "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:4848/theme/META-INF/com_sun_faces_ajax.js"

Comment: Update: I ran netstat again, and it doesn't list any 4848 now, so maybe the opened browser held connections on the port.

Comment: That's very strange behaviour! The only thing I can think of that might mean one browser can open it and the other can't with a 404 is maybe a caching issue? Can FF still open the page if you use private browsing? Or can Chrome open the page if you use incognito mode?

Comment: Firefox can open it in private browsing. And Chrome can also open it in incognito mode.
Maybe some of my Chrome plugins cause this problem? I tried to turn off AdBlock, but nothing changed.

Comment: Another strange thing: when I click on the links of the admin panel in Chrome, my CPU is at 100%, and opening the pages take some seconds. But in Firefox it happens at normal speed and there's no CPU overload.

Comment: Chrome does normally disable extensions in incognito mode, so it seems plausible. It not being a glassfish problem means this is all outside my experience! I can't advise on how to debug browsers. If incognito mode works for Chrome, have you tried forcing a refresh? Ctrl + R or Shift + F5?

Comment: Now I started Glassfish again, and opened the admin panel in Chrome incognito mode, and the speed is normal, there's no overload. Forced refresh works well in incognito mode. When I'm not in incognito mode, it doesn't help. So yes it's an issue with (my) Chrome, and not with Glassfish. Thanks for your help!:) I'll shut down my plugins one by one to find out which one causes the problem.

Answer (score 4):

not sure if this is still a problem but I got something similiar and I could resolve this by setting an admin password and enabling secure-admin (glassfish 3.1). Not sure if the secure-admin is necessary though, so setting a password might be enough.

1. download and extract glassfish zip
2. `glassfish3/bin/asadmin start-domain`
3. `glassfish3/bin/asadmin change-admin-password` (default is user "admin" with no password, so just hit [ENTER] two times)
4. `glassfish3/bin/asadmin enable-secure-admin` (might be skipped, just see what works for you)
5. `glassfish3/bin/asadmin restart-domain`

Now the admin-gui should be available on `http://localhost:4848` and also from other machines via `http://your.ip.or.address:4848`

Good luck

Answer (score 4):

I've had this happen to me when I enable "Default Principal To Role Mapping":

[image: Default Principal To Role Mapping]

After I enable this and restart the domain, I'm never able to login again. I had to change the following line on domain.xml (with the domain stopped) :

```
<security-service default-principal-password="admin" activate-default-principal-to-role-mapping="true" default-principal="admin">
```

to this:

```
<security-service>
```

Comment: The same is true if you change the JACC provider to something else. It does not only add jacc="my_provider" to the domain.xml, but also that default-principal & default-principal-password stuff. This will result in a an empty response / blank page and http 200 with content-length: 0 after "logging in" to the admin console from remote! Solution is to only leave in <security-service jacc="my_provider">.

Comment: Ah seems like it also works to remove the "Default Principal" & "Password" in the GUI before saving. At least in 3.1.2.2 they are always pre-filled but will be omitted from the xml file when delete before saving in the GUI.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find any serious error in your log. Maybe another program doesn't let GlassFish works correctly. For example antivirus.

Comment: Thanks for the idea! I'm using Avast. I turned off all modules but the problem still remains.

Comment: What program exactly does take 100% of CPU time?

Comment: As I remember from yesterday, java.exe does. But now I can't reproduce the problem... now I can open the admin panel in Chrome :O I don't know what happened.

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar problem.

It happened when I put a primefaces 5.x jar file in my /JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/ext directory and when I removed it all went back to normal.

Through research I found that apparently the admingui clashes with some "3rd party JSF helper stuff".

Hope this helps somebody.

Answer (score 1):

When Running on Chrome you may get this error due to this issue. https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/glassfish/issues/22439

Admin gui is accessible on Firefox though.

Answer (score 0):

Try this : http://mike.meessen.biz/blog/?p=281

I had exact

> first there's a page saying "The Admin Console is starting. Please
>   wait.", then it tries to redirect to a page having title "Login", but
>   it loads, loads, loads forever.

problem and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I was in a similar situation and I found that in FF I cannot get access to console but in IE and Chrome with `http://localhost:4848/login.jsf` I can.

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse stopping the server and cleaning maybe will help. Afterwards you can access it via http://localhost:4848/common/index.jsf

Answer (score -2):

The solution is quite simple.
There is an apllication/project that you were working on that had some errors. Simply undeploy them using the following procedure:

1.Go to **Services** tab then **Servers** then **Glassfish Server 4.1**

2.Right click on Glassfish Server 4.1 and click on the dropdown to list what under Glassfish Servers.

3.Expand **Applications** and undeploy all applications to start full receovery of the admin console.

4.Start Glassfish

5.Launch the  [admin console](http://localhost:4848/common/index.jsf)

Comment: You are ignoring the fact that the admin console is not reachable in the first place.

Comment: Undeploy the buggy application and admin gui will be available

Comment: Did you even read my comment? The problem is the web admin console is not reachable from `http://www.your_domain.com:4848` So you can't do all the above. The correct thing you can do is to use the command line and run `asadmin undeploy your_application_name` I just wanted you to note that but you have fervently ignored my hint and for that I am downvoting your answer because your wrong answer is not the correct kind of wrong answer. hehehe

Answer (score -4):

Make your domain writeable thats the key guys
it ll work no need to other kinda wierd stuff